# jQuery how to store elements for append() or clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a very simple expand boxes. the Structure is like below

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="item"> </div>  
    <div class="outside"> </div>  <!-- append '.item''s children to '.outside'  -->
    <div class="item"> </div>
    <div class="item"> </div> 
</div>
```

I'd like to achieve is that, if a box is opened, contents can be viewed immediately when you click another box. ( Do not need to `slideUp` and `slideDown` again)

The problem I am having is that, If you click the first box `box 1`, you can see the slider correctly, then you click `box 2`, the contents can be showed properly as well, and then you click back to `box 1`, contents won't show. I understand `append` all `.inside` children to `'.outside'` contents can be view only once as `append` moves elements to `.outside`, if I use `clone()`, I can view the contents but will lose a working slider.

so my question is do I need to append `.inside` children to `'.outside'` first then move everything back to where is was? if someone could help please? Thanks!

**Online Sample http://jsfiddle.net/ny4sx/**

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1
        <div class="inside">
            <ul class="slider">
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var $outside = $('<div class="outside"></div>');
var $closebutton = $('<div class="close">x</div>');
$outside.append($closebutton);


$('.item').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active');


    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass("active");
    }
    if $this.next().hasClass('outside')) {
    console.log('yes');
} else {
    console.log('no');
    $outside.insertAfter(this).css({
        'height': 300
    }).slideDown();

}

$('.close').click(function () {
    $('.outside').remove();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

});

});

//Slider FROM Here

// settings
var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

function slides() {
    return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
$interval = setInterval(

function () {
    var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

    slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
    slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

    if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

    slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
    slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
},
$transition_time + $time_between_slides);
```

Comment: huh... why removing/appending... simple show/hide should work better, imho.... p.s. if you click few (3) times on same button - same thing happens -> content is removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you consider something like this or is it too different from what you expect.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" data-content="1">1</div>
    <div class="item" data-content="2">2</div>
    <div class="item" data-content="3">3</div>
    <div class="outside">
        <div class="close">x</div>
        <div class='content content1'>
            <ul class="slider">
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='content content2'>
            <h1>this is item 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class='content content3'>
            <h1>this is item 3</h1>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, aliquam, dolorum ipsa perferendis iure quibusdam consequuntur nulla reiciendis velit aut modi reprehenderit. Sit, mollitia, natus odio repellat neque error voluptatem.</p>            
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.item').click(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var contentNumber = $this.data("content");

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass("active");

    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content'+contentNumber).show();
    $('.outside').slideDown();     
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.outside').slideUp();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ny4sx/43/)

Answer (score 1):

I played with it a little here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ny4sx/37/

A summary of my edits:

```
    var savedContent = $('.outside .content').children();
    var target = $('.outside').prev().children().first();
    console.dir(target);
    $('.outside .content').remove();
    target.append(savedContent);
```

Not the cleanest (I was doing a lot of trial and error), but I figured out what the issue was.  You were deleting the contents before you saved a reference to it, there fore it was not persisting.  I would definitely do it the way that MamaWalkter proposed, though.